# Error: Call to a member function persist() on a non-object

Tags: php, symfony

Not sure what I am doing wrong and similar answers to this problem aren't helping either. It happens after the form is submitted.

Error message:

> FatalErrorException: Error: Call to a member function persist() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\EliteFifa2\src\EliteFifa\Bundle\Manager\BaseManager.php line 18

UserController:

```
public function selectTeamAction(Request $request)
{
    $userManager = $this->get('elite_fifa.user_manager');
    $loggedInUser = $userManager->getLoggedInUser();

    $teamManager = $this->get('elite_fifa.team_manager');

    $teams = $teamManager->getTeamsWithoutAManager();
    $teamChoices = array();
    foreach ($teams as $team) {
        $teamChoices[$team->getId()] = $team->getName();
    }

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->add('teams', 'choice', array(
            'choices' => $teamChoices,
        ))
        ->add('save', 'submit')
        ->getForm();

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $data = $form->getData();
        $selectedTeam = $teamManager->getTeamById($data['teams']);
        $loggedInUser->setTeam($selectedTeam);
        $userManager->persist($loggedInUser);
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('task_success'));
    }

    return $this->render('EliteFifaBundle:User:selectTeam.html.twig', array(
        'teams' => $teams,
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ));
}
```

UserManager:

```
class UserManager extends BaseManager
{
    private $userRepository;
    private $loggedInUser;

    public function __construct(UserRepository $userRepository, User $loggedInUser)
    {
        $this->userRepository = $userRepository;
        $this->loggedInUser = $loggedInUser;
    }

    public function createUser()
    {
        return new User();
    }

    public function getLoggedInUser()
    {
        return $this->loggedInUser;
    }

    public function getUserByUsername($username)
    {
        return $this->userRepository->findOneByUsername($username);
    }
}
```

BaseManager:

```
class BaseManager
{
    private $entityManager;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    public function persist($entity)
    {
        $this->entityManager->persist($entity);
        $this->entityManager->flush();
    }

    public function remove($entity)
    {
        $this->entityManager->remove($entity);
        $this->entityManager->flush();
    }
}
```

Services.yml:

```
parameters:
user_repository.class:              EliteFifa\Bundle\Repository\UserRepository
user_repository.factory_argument:   'EliteFifaBundle:User'
role_repository.class:              EliteFifa\Bundle\Repository\RoleRepository
role_repository.factory_argument:   'EliteFifaBundle:Role'
team_repository.class:              EliteFifa\Bundle\Repository\TeamRepository
team_repository.factory_argument:   'EliteFifaBundle:Team'
match_repository.class:             EliteFifa\Bundle\Repository\MatchRepository
match_repository.factory_argument:  'EliteFifaBundle:Match'
user_manager.class:                 EliteFifa\Bundle\Manager\UserManager
base_manager.class:                 EliteFifa\Bundle\Manager\BaseManager
role_manager.class:                 EliteFifa\Bundle\Manager\RoleManager
team_manager.class:                 EliteFifa\Bundle\Manager\TeamManager
match_manager.class:                EliteFifa\Bundle\Manager\MatchManager


services:
    elite_fifa.base_manager:
        class: %base_manager.class%
        arguments: [@doctrine.orm.entity_manager]

    elite_fifa.user_manager:
        class: %user_manager.class%
        arguments:
          - @elite_fifa.user_repository
          - @=service('security.context').getToken().getUser()

    elite_fifa.role_manager:
        class: %role_manager.class%
        arguments:
          - @elite_fifa.role_repository

    elite_fifa.team_manager:
        class: %team_manager.class%
        arguments:
          - @elite_fifa.team_repository

    elite_fifa.match_manager:
        class: %match_manager.class%
        arguments:
          - @elite_fifa.match_repository

    elite_fifa.user_repository:
        class:           %user_repository.class%
        factory_service: doctrine.orm.entity_manager
        factory_method:  getRepository
        arguments:
          - %user_repository.factory_argument%

    elite_fifa.role_repository:
        class:           %role_repository.class%
        factory_service: doctrine.orm.entity_manager
        factory_method:  getRepository
        arguments:
          - %role_repository.factory_argument%

    elite_fifa.team_repository:
        class:           %team_repository.class%
        factory_service: doctrine.orm.entity_manager
        factory_method:  getRepository
        arguments:
          - %team_repository.factory_argument%

    elite_fifa.match_repository:
        class:           %match_repository.class%
        factory_service: doctrine.orm.entity_manager
        factory_method:  getRepository
        arguments:
          - %match_repository.factory_argument%
```

Comment: `var_dump($this->entityManager);` You're not passing `$entityManager` to the `BaseManager` constructor so it's expected to be `NULL`. To be precise - you're not even calling `BaseManager` constructor.

Comment: @zerkms I get FatalErrorException: Error: Call to undefined method EliteFifa\Bundle\Controller\UserController::getEntityManager()

Comment: yep. Now you know why it happens

Comment: But aren't I passing $entityManager to BaseManager using dependency injecting in services.yml? And then calling UserManager which extends BaseManager

Comment: you aren't instantiating `BaseManager` instance for that to happen

Comment: @zerkms I see, is there a way to automatically instantiate BaseManager whenever a subclass is called?

Comment: you need to add the 3rd argument to `UserManager` constructor and call `parent::__construct()` from it. PS: it's php basics, I've been thinking anyone who starts using sf2 is supposed to know it :-S

Comment: @zerkms You know what, I actually just realised that after I commented ha. I code mostly in Java so I forget some of the basic PHP stuff when I switch back :D Thanks!

Comment: in Java you also have to invoke a parent non-default constructor manually, haven't you? :-)